# How to provide a state to InsertOptionValueRequest

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, metadata, dynamics-crm-2015

When trying to define a `statuscode` custom value using `InsertOptionValueRequest`, I'm getting the following message:

> When creating a new status value, you must provide what state value
>   that status is associated with

What I currently have is:

```
var response = orgContext.Execute(new InsertOptionValueRequest
{
    AttributeLogicalName = "statuscode",
    EntityLogicalName = "op_employeragreement",
    Label = new Label("Under review", 1033),
    Value = 2
});
```

How am I supposed to provide an associated `state`? These are the class properties (taken from `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll, v7.0.0.0` (CRM 2015):

```
namespace Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Messages
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts")]
    public sealed class InsertOptionValueRequest : OrganizationRequest
    {
        public InsertOptionValueRequest();

        public string AttributeLogicalName { get; set; }
        public Label Description { get; set; }
        public string EntityLogicalName { get; set; }
        public Label Label { get; set; }
        public string OptionSetName { get; set; }
        public string SolutionUniqueName { get; set; }
        public int? Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't contain a `State` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you are using the wrong thing; `InsertOptionValueRequest` is for option sets (picklists). Status selector doesnt fall into category.

I think you want to be using `InsertStatusValueRequest`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.insertstatusvaluerequest.aspx).